# SSL Support in .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, ssl, compact-framework, tcpclient

I have a class that is written for the .NET Compact Framework 3.5 which is nothing more than a wrapper for the System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient class.

I would like my class to support SSL between the client and the server, but it appears as though the CF doesn't support it. More specifically, the System.Net.Security namespace (which is where the SslStream class lives) is not included in the CF.

How can I support SSL in my TcpClient wrapper that is targeted for the .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

Comment: On researching this topic for HTTPS stuff, I did find: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738067.aspx#SSLwiththe.NETCompactFramework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is to use the components in [SSLBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product. It is available for .NET CF (as well as .NET desktop, mono and Silverlight).